# Listing engine evaluation of each game after opening to track my opening skill level

Tags: opening, database, scid

I've recently picked up the book "Pump up your rating" where the author talks about tracking each of your games with a post-mortem analysis. The report of all your games combined will show you in the long run which areas of your chess game are holding you back.

Inspired by this approach I want to understand which openings I'm playing correctly and which ones I need to study in more detail. I've downloaded my chess games and have tried to analyse them using ChessX, Scid vs Pc and Lucas Chess. Scid vs Pc gives me the option to automatically annotate the games but stores the engine score in a non tabular format. I can only see the evaluation of the moves when opening a specific game.

Ideally I want to add a column to my chess games in a database which shows the engine evaluation of the game at the end of the "Opening".

After some research I found that move 10-12 are commonly accepted as the end of the "Opening". I haven't found a way to programmatically extract the engine evaluation at move 10 or 12 from all my games. Scid vs Pc allows you to add user defined flags but this is just a text string.

I'm very new to chess databases and engines in general and would be greateful for any advice on how to achieve this.

Comment: You'll learn that this is nonsense. You can play the openings with open books, laptops running, advice from grandmasters sitting beside you, and where does that get you? An equal middlegame.  Don't waste the time I wasted; invest your limited study time in the aspects of the game where games are won and lost: endgames and tactics.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you eleborate further on why the analysis would result in nonsense? For me, getting to an equal middlegame would be helpful as currently I end up being worse out of the opening and therefore in the middlegame which as a result doesn't get me to a won endgame or favourable tactics. I want to spend my time studying openings as efficiently as possible by only looking at the openings that I face in my current level. Analysing which opening I am weakest in and face most frequently would allow me to improve the quickest. Curious to hear your further thoughts

Answer (score 1):

It is good to review games to see why you lost.

Just tracking your alleged 'rating' per some engine after each game is useless as you 'rating' is not that stable until you have a lot of experience and even then there is a wide variation on any given day for most players.